# How to use an Azure SAS when trying to copy an Azure File to an Azure Blob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files

I have a private Azure Blob. I'm trying to copy Azure File(s) over to the blob.
These are both in the same Storage account.

When I try to copy the Azure file to the Blob, I'm getting a 404.

e.g. : `await destinationBlob.StartCopyAsync(sourceCloudFile);`

Assumption: This is because I need to provide a [Shared Access Signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2) on the Azure File.

So, I'm not sure how to use the SAS to copy the File to the Blob.

```
var policy = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.SharedAccessFilePolicy()
{
    Permissions = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.SharedAccessFilePermissions.List,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1))
};
var sasToken = source.CloudFile.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);

destinationBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";
```

Ok - I have the token .. now what?

Answer (score 2):

Please change the permission in your `SharedAccessFilePolicy`. In order to copy a file, the permission should be `Read` and not `List`.

```
var policy = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.SharedAccessFilePolicy()
{
    Permissions = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1)
};
```

Once you get the SAS, you would simply create a SAS URL for the file and call `StartCopy` on your `CloudBlockBlob` object.

```
var sasToken = source.CloudFile.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
var fileSasUri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}{1}", source.CloudFile.Uri.AbsoluteUri, sasToken));
var copyId = await destinationBlob.StartCopyAsync(fileSasUri);
```

To set the content type of the destination blob, after the copy has been completed you can do something like:

```
destinationBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";
await destinationBlob.SetPropertiesAsync();
```

Comment: Ah! ta (was also a bad copy/paste). But what do i do, next? I have this string url... so how do i use it?

Comment: Woot! 50% works!! The file is now copied (yay) but the `ContentType` is ... empty? It's not even `application/octet` or whatever the default is. I've updated the opening post to show exactly what I'm trying.  Can `StartCopyAsync` set the `ContentType` properties?

Comment: What's the content type of the source file? `Copy Blob` operation will simply copy the content type of the source file and set the content type of the blob to that value. You can't specify the content type of the destination blob at the time of copying. You would need to perform another operation to set the blob's properties.

Comment: :( `The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.` I'm assuming this is because the copy hasn't completed?

Comment: Ok - found the solution. You said "_Copy Blob operation will simply copy the content type of the source file and set the content type of the blob to that value._". This means it will (1) copy data & (2) copy properties. So, I've set the Azure File properties, then copyasync :) worked! e.g.: `source.CloudFile.Properties.ContentType = "<whatever>"; await source.CloudFile.SetPropertiesAsync(); await destinationBlob.StartCopyAsync(fileSasUri);` :) :)